# What is the name for this rotary switch scheme?

Tags: switches

I am trying to figure out just exactly how this rotary switch works and what it's called (so that I can research it). There are usually 6-8 pads which are shorted to a common pad through fingers. That's easy enough... however, I don't believe these are acting as individual switches if that makes sense. I think they are multiplexed to one pin.

[image: Rotary Switch]

Comment: Look up something called *"focus"*, then learn to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X Pole by Y Way (with N detents) Rotary switch. THese are so custom, you wont find many like yours.   ( if any ) But you need to know the state table for inputs connected to outputs for each position.

e.g. 1 pole 8 way rotary

Comment: Seems legit....

Comment: By the way( no pun intended ) there is too much solder on your "ways" and one is almost shorting out. Or just a bad photo... suck it up with solder sucker or gauze braid.